# D3 force-directed: why transform-translate tick is required when displaying labels

Tags: d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I am looking at [samples](https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8) of D3 force-directed graphs with node labels, and I realised that for the tick function, the function to governing the movement of the node and labels uses a transform-translate method:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
```

instead of the usual without labels.

```
nodes.attr({"cx":function(d){return d.x;},
            "cy":function(d){return d.y;}
        });
```

Would anyone be able to help explain the rationle? Thanks.

Comment: That's because in that code you shared `node` is a group (`<g>`) selection, and groups have neither `cx` nor `cy` attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When node is a single shape element, we just adjust its positional attributes in the tick function. For eg. if it is a circle, we update its cx and cy attributes.

But when we have multiple elements to be displayed in the same or relative position, we group the elements using `<g>` element and apply the positional attribute to the `<g>` element. The positional attribute of `g` element is `transform`. We can create different type of elements (here - circle and text) and adjust their positions independently in the tick function. However, it is better to group elements in such cases.